# Given that $\;\sin^3x\sin3x = \sum^n_{m=0}C_m\cos mx\,,\; C_n \neq 0\;$ is an identity . Find the value of n.

Tags: trigonometry

Problem :

Given that $\sin^3 x \sin 3x = \sum^n_{m=0}C_m \cos mx, C_n \neq 0 $ is an identity. Find the value of n.

I tried : $\sin3x = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x$ but unable to reach to any point.... Please suggest further ....Thanks..

Comment: hint: you get $sin^3xsin3x=3sin^4x-4sin^6x$ but we also know that $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$ and that $cos(3x)=4cos^3x-3cosx$. You should combine between the identities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the identity
$$
\sin^3(x)=\frac{3\sin(x)-\sin(3x)}{4}
$$
and the identity
$$
\sin(ax)\sin(bx)=\frac12\big(\cos((a-b)x)-\cos((a+b)x)\big)
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^3(x)\sin(3x)
&=\frac{3\sin(x)-\sin(3x)}{4}\sin(3x)\\
&=\frac38\big(\cos(2x)-\cos(4x)\big)-\frac18\big(\cos(0x)-\cos(6x)\big)\\
&=\frac18\big(\cos(6x)-3\cos(4x)+3\cos(2x)-\cos(0x)\big)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $n=6$.

Comment: $$\sin(ax)\sin(bx)=\frac12\big(\cos((a-b)x)-\cos((a+b)x)\big)$$ has a cleaner form $\sin A\sin B=\frac12\cdot \big(\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\big)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: simpler in form, but essentially the same. However, I customized it to fit the problem at hand. It didn't seem an excessive crime :-)

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

As you have noticed, $4\sin^3x=3\sin x-\sin3x,$

$$\text{So, }\sin^3x\sin3x=\frac{(3\sin x-\sin3x)\sin3x}4=\frac{3(2\sin x\sin3x)-2\sin^23x}8$$

As $2\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B),$

$\implies  2\sin x\sin3x=\cos(3x-x)-\cos(3x+x)=\cos2x-\cos4x$

and as $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y\implies 2\sin^2y=1-\cos2y,$

$\implies 2\sin^23x=1-\cos6x$

Comment: (+1) essentially the same answer at essentially the same time.

Answer (score 3):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286475/why-does-this-fourier-series-have-a-finite-number-of-terms/286488#286488). Note that, the function $ \sin^3 x \sin 3x  $ is an even function, so its Fourier series will have expansion in terms of the functions $\cos mx$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, where

> $$ C_m = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^3 x \sin 3x   \cos(mx)\, dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi \sin^3 x \sin 3x   \cos(mx)\, dx, \quad m \ge 0.$$

Now, just work out the integral and you will be able to finish the problem. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1370282529317&fp=1&i=integrate(+sin(x)%5e3+sin(3x)cos(m+x)%2c+x%3d0..Pi+)&incTime=true) for the value of the integral and you will see that the Fourier series has finite number of terms.

**Note:** This solution is based on the [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) knowledge. I just paid attention to the tag.

Comment: (+1) This *is* the general way to work these kinds of problems, just a bit advanced for the apparent level of the question. For instance, it's not certain that integrals are in scope.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, you are right. You got the point. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

$n=6$.

Since $\sin^3x \sin 3 x$ is a degree $6$ polynomial of $\cos x$, and $\cos nx$ is degree $n$ polynomial of $\cos x$, $n$ must be $6$.

Comment: Some more explanation might be nice, since the same reasoning was just used to justify $n=4$.

Comment: @robjohn I missed a $3$ in $\sin 3x$ previously.

Comment: @robjohn: My solution explains it.

Comment: Why is $\sin^3(x)\sin(3x)$ a polynomial of $\cos(x)$? Given that, why is it degree $6$? Why is $\cos(nx)$ a degree $n$ polynomial of $\cos(x)$? These things are probably not obvious to a trigonometry student (I am making this assumption because of the question and the tags).

Comment: @robjohn: You are right. I think this my solution is a little bit advance for the OP. I just paid attention to the tag. However it is a correct solution.

Comment: @robjohn: I added a link.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Your answer is a bit advanced for the level of the question, but I think you've intercepted someone else's message.