# Expressing $\cos(x)^6$ as a linear combination of $\cos(kx)$'s

Tags: trigonometry

Let $$(\cos^6(x)) = m\cos(6x)+n\cos(5x)+o\cos(4x)+p\cos(3x)+q\cos(2x)+r\cos(x)+a.$$

What is the value of $a$?

Comment: Look up the product-to-sum identity.

Comment: I gave a general approach to the [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410343/given-that-sin3x-sin3x-sumn-m-0c-m-cos-mx-c-n-neq-0-is-an-id) using Fourier series techniques.

Comment: since $a$ is constant just plug in one nice value for $x$ (for example $\pi$) and you're done. (given the fact that you already know all the other coefficients, otherwise you have to plug in several values and solve a linear system)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\cos^{6}\pars{x}&=\pars{\expo{\ic x} + \expo{-\ic x} \over 2}^{6}=
{1 \over 2^{6}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{6}{6 \choose \ell}\expo{\ic\pars{6 - 2\ell}x}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2^{6}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{2}{6 \choose \ell}\expo{\ic\pars{6 - 2\ell}x}
+{1 \over 2^{6}} \overbrace{6 \choose 3}^{\ds{20}}
+
{1 \over 2^{6}}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{\ell = 4}^{6}{6 \choose \ell}\expo{\ic\pars{6 - 2\ell}x}}
\tag{1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> \color{#f00}{\sum_{\ell = 4}^{6}{6 \choose \ell}\expo{\ic\pars{6 - 2\ell}x}}&=
> \sum_{\ell = -2}^{0}{6 \choose \ell + 6}\expo{\ic\pars{-6 - 2\ell}x}
> =
> \sum_{\ell = 2}^{0}\overbrace{6 \choose -\ell + 6}^{\ds{6 \choose \ell}}\
> \expo{\ic\pars{-6 + 2\ell}x}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \color{#f00}{\sum_{\ell = 0}^{2}{6 \choose \ell}\expo{\ic\pars{-6 + 2\ell}x}}
> \end{align}

We'll replace this result in $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}
\cos^{6}\pars{x}&={5 \over 16}
+ {1 \over 32}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{2}{6 \choose \ell}\cos\pars{\bracks{6 - 2\ell}x}
={5 \over 16} + {\cos\pars{6x} + 6\cos\pars{4x} + 15\cos\pars{2x}\over 32}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large\cos^{6}\pars{x}
> ={5 \over 16} + {15 \over 32}\,\cos\pars{2x} + {3 \over 16}\,\cos\pars{4x}
> + {1 \over 32}\,\cos\pars{6x}}
> $$

Comment: I cant read it :( .. is it LateX code ?

Comment: @user47252 Yes, it's $\tt LaTeX$. I use some macros to write the code in a comfortable way.

Comment: How do I read it ? Do I have to install LateX ?

Comment: @user47252 You can read it in the web page with a browser. [Just here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/686817/85343) .

Answer (score 0):

**Method** $1:$

Use $\displaystyle\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A\iff \cos^3A=\cdots$ for $\displaystyle\cos^6x=(\cos^3x)^2$

and $\displaystyle\cos2B=2\cos^2B-1\iff \cos^2B=\cdots$

**Method** $2:$

Using [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html), $\displaystyle\cos y=\frac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}2$

Answer (score 0):

If:
$$\cos^6(x)=\sum_{k=1}^6 a_k \cos(kx)+a_0$$ 
Then we have:
$$\cos^6(0)+\cos^6(\pi)=2=a_2+ a_4+a_6+2a_0$$ 
$$\cos^6(3\pi/4)+\cos^6(\pi/4)=1/4=-2a_4+2a_0$$
$$\cos^6(3\pi/2)+\cos^6(\pi/2)=0=-2a_2+2a_4-2a_6+2a_0$$
Add them all up to find $a_0$.